# How to obtain the validated class with ConstraintValidatorContext

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I am adding a custom annotation constraint at class level as follows:

```
@PasswordMatch(message = "Given passwords don't match")
public class RegistrationDto {

    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirmation;
    ...
```

The PasswordMatchValidator looks like:

```
public class PasswordMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordMatch, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object object, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        RegistrationDto registrationDto = (RegistrationDto) object;

        String password = registrationDto.getPassword();
        String passwordConfirmation = registrationDto.getPasswordConfirmation();

       return password.equals(passwordConfirmation);
    }
}
```

This works fine, as long as I know that the class I am checking is of type RegistrationDto. My question is:

**How can I generalize this annotation so that I can use it for other dtos as well?**

My current approach is to use an interface:

```
@PasswordMatch(message = "Given passwords don't match")
public class RegistrationDto implements PasswordMatchCheckable {

    private String password;
    private String passwordConfirmation;
    ...
```

```
public interface PasswordMatchCheckable {

    String getPassword();
    String getPasswordConfirmation();
}
```

```
public class PasswordMatchValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PasswordMatch, PasswordMatchCkeckable> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(PasswordMatchCkeckable dto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        String password = dto.getPassword();
        String passwordConfirmation = dto.getPasswordConfirmation();

       return password.equals(passwordConfirmation);
    }
}
```

This seems to be a bit better, but I'm still not completely convinced.

Is there a better way to obtain the annotated class and check whether we can perform a password match validation? What can we do with the ConstraintValidatorContext? I couldn't come up with a cool solution, but I don't wanna give up until someone tells me that there is no better way.

Many thanks

Comment: The interface approach is what I usually do.

Comment: Note that it's common to return `true` if the object to check (`dto`) is `null`. That prevents `NullPointerExceptions` if the DTO is `null`. It's then usually combined with `@NotNull`.

Comment: @RobSpoor, thanks for the response. I will include the check for null.